# In which parts of Costa Rica do I need a 4x4 in during dry season?

Tags: car-rentals, automobiles, costa-rica

I find a lot of comments on cars in Costa Rica recommending 4x4 cars. However, the reasoning is always the heavy rain (earth might move or rivers flooding etc.). On the other hand I found a few reports about pretty good road conditions in general and no recommendations for the dry season.

I would prefer a small car if feasible. Has anyone been to Costa Rica in dry season and can give advice?

We'll be there in march.

The route is roughly

- Osa Peninsula
- West Coast to La Fortuna
- Nicoya Peninsula
- Puerto Limón

We don't plan to go further north, e.g. Liberia, Caño Negro or Barra del Colorado and to the souther central part, i.e. we will stay closer to the coast in Puntarenas and Limón.

Comment: I can't answer the question, but to help those who could: to me "*street conditions*" implies an urban environment, whereas when travelling between cities I'd talk about "*road conditions*". Could you clarify whether you're planning to stay in San José or travel more widely?

Comment: The structure of your question isn't really suited for Travel because you are asking for open ended advice, and as such is headed for doom.  You should check out [What topics can I ask about](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  But the good news is that you could edit it it into something more suitable.  EG Explicitly ask "Do I need a 4x4 in Costa Rica to drive in area X during the dry season?"

Comment: @PeterTaylor good point, changed it to "road conditions" (not my first language).

Comment: @PeterM I tried to be more specific. Might still be to broad of a geographical region for good advice? Haven't been there and it's quite hard to find information.